# Change JSON object index between Fragments

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I am looking to change the JSON object index from inside my QueryUtils.java file between my Fragments.

This line right here to be more precise:

```
JSONObject currentDay = dayArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

I have 7 fragments and I wanna change the index from 0 to 1, 2 and so on for each fragment and after searching quite a white I couldn't actually find a way of doing so.

Comment: can you post your code what tried?

Comment: @akhilesh0707 Well, not much to show but failed attempts. I basically created a fragment adapter to override the Fragment getItem method and set a numbered position to each fragment and initially thought I could use that in my query utils to display the active fragment and change the index.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this can help u

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  private static final String KEY = "pos_id";

  public static MyFragment newInstance(int pos) {

      MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putInt(KEY, pos);
      myFragment.setArguments(args);

      return myFragment;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int pos = getArguments().getInt(KEY)
    //TODO ur Query
  }

}
```

Comment: I agree with this solution. Either pass the index to the fragment on creation and let the fragment query it's own data, OR pass the data to the fragment if you already have it (`public static MyFragment newInstance(JSONObject currentDay){...}`).